# Capturing the pointer on whole window

Tags: c#, pointers, canvas, uwp, mouse

Is there a way to capture a pointer in UWP when PointerPressed occurs on a Shape object that is on a Canvas but then handling the mouse move independently from the Shape?

E. g. I've got a class that contains a shape which is added to my Canvas. So my basic event base look's like this:

```
myShapeClass.PointerPressed += myShapeClass_PointerPressed;
myShapeClass.PointerMoved += myShapeClass_PointerMoved;
myShapeClass.PointerReleased += myShapeClass_PointerReleased;
```

PointerMoved basically just does some transformation to the shape, but the pointer should always be in the center of the shape. But when I move the pointer too fast, the shape doesn't draw fast enough and the pointer get's out of the shape so the event doesn't occur anymore.

Aside from the canvas there can be many shapes on it so adding event handlers to every one of it is quite troublesome. Is there a way to capture a pointer and then follow it no matter where it is on the screen? And of course trigger the PointerReleased or another release event outside of my shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe these events on `Window.Current.CoreWindow` to get them fired everytime.